# User authentication on Resin webserver

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver, resin, caucho

I'm currently tasked with replacing an `Apache` + `Resin` Java web server with a `Resin-only` configuration.

Currently in our apache setup, we use .htaccess and a small user database to provide passwording at a directory level.

Does anyone know the equivalent setup when using just `Resin` as the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Authentication on Resin](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/security/authentication.xtp)"

The closest you'll come to .htaccess with apache is configuring for Basic auth using an XmlAuthenticator. You'll need to convert your htpasswd file into the XML format that resin uses.

Follow the "Quick Start" section and you'll get what you want.